# Errors converting EXRs to mp4 with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg 4.3.1 to convert some EXRs to mp4, with tone mapping for the extended range in the source and rec709 conversion for the mp4.

I'm using this command:

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob  -framerate 24 -i 'frames/*.exr' -vf zscale=transfer=linear,tonemap=hable,zscale=transfer=bt709,format=yuv420p -c:v libx264 -r 24 -preset slow -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p foo-tonemap-01.mp4
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Input #0, image2, from 'frames/*.exr':
  Duration: 00:00:00.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: exr, gbrapf32le, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (exr (native) -> h264 (libx264))
code 3074: no path between colorspaces
Error while filtering: Generic error in an external library
```

What does that error "no path between colorspaces" mean? Do I need to tell it what colorspace the EXRs are in (scene-linear RGB) or something?

Complete log:

```
ffmpeg started on 2020-08-05 at 22:22:33
Report written to "ffmpeg-20200805-222233.log"
Log level: 48
Command line:
ffmpeg -report -y -i frames/0240.exr -vf "zscale=transfer=linear,tonemap=clip,zscale=transfer=bt709,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -r 24 -preset slow -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p foo-tonemap-01.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Splitting the commandline.
Reading option '-report' ... matched as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite output files) with argument '1'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'frames/0240.exr'.
Reading option '-vf' ... matched as option 'vf' (set video filters) with argument 'zscale=transfer=linear,tonemap=clip,zscale=transfer=bt709,format=yuv420p'.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'libx264'.
Reading option '-r' ... matched as option 'r' (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument '24'.
Reading option '-preset' ... matched as AVOption 'preset' with argument 'slow'.
Reading option '-crf' ... matched as AVOption 'crf' with argument '18'.
Reading option '-pix_fmt' ... matched as option 'pix_fmt' (set pixel format) with argument 'yuv420p'.
Reading option 'foo-tonemap-01.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option report (generate a report) with argument 1.
Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Parsing a group of options: input url frames/0240.exr.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an input file: frames/0240.exr.
[NULL @ 0x6db71c0] Opening 'frames/0240.exr' for reading
[file @ 0x6db7c80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
[exr_pipe @ 0x6db71c0] Format exr_pipe probed with size=2048 and score=51
[exr_pipe @ 0x6db71c0] Before avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 0 bytes read:32768 seeks:0 nb_streams:1
[exr_pipe @ 0x6db71c0] parser not found for codec exr, packets or times may be invalid.
[exr_pipe @ 0x6db71c0] parser not found for codec exr, packets or times may be invalid.
[exr @ 0x6db92c0] line order: 0.
[exr_pipe @ 0x6db71c0] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 4970635 bytes read:4970635 seeks:0 frames:1
Input #0, exr_pipe, from 'frames/0240.exr':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 1, 1/25: Video: exr, gbrapf32le, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url foo-tonemap-01.mp4.
Applying option vf (set video filters) with argument zscale=transfer=linear,tonemap=clip,zscale=transfer=bt709,format=yuv420p.
Applying option c:v (codec name) with argument libx264.
Applying option r (set frame rate (Hz value, fraction or abbreviation)) with argument 24.
Applying option pix_fmt (set pixel format) with argument yuv420p.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: foo-tonemap-01.mp4.
[file @ 0x6e0a0c0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto,data'
Successfully opened the file.
detected 32 logical cores
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (exr (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:0 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
[exr @ 0x6dbe700] line order: 0.
[Parsed_zscale_0 @ 0x725c4c0] Setting 'transfer' to value 'linear'
[Parsed_tonemap_1 @ 0x725c940] Setting 'tonemap' to value 'clip'
[Parsed_zscale_2 @ 0x725d380] Setting 'transfer' to value 'bt709'
[Parsed_format_3 @ 0x725e100] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x725eb40] Setting 'video_size' to value '1920x1080'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x725eb40] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value '180'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x725eb40] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/25'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x725eb40] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '1/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x725eb40] Setting 'frame_rate' to value '25/1'
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x725eb40] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:gbrapf32le tb:1/25 fr:25/1 sar:1/1
[format @ 0x725fc00] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x6dc0000] query_formats: 7 queried, 6 merged, 0 already done, 0 delayed
[Parsed_zscale_0 @ 0x725c4c0] w:1920 h:1080 fmt:gbrapf32le sar:1/1 -> w:1920 h:1080 fmt:gbrapf32le sar:1/1
[Parsed_zscale_2 @ 0x725d380] w:1920 h:1080 fmt:gbrapf32le sar:1/1 -> w:1920 h:1080 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1
[Parsed_zscale_0 @ 0x725c4c0] w:1920 h:1080 fmt:gbrapf32le sar:1/1 -> w:1920 h:1080 fmt:gbrapf32le sar:1/1
code 3074: no path between colorspaces
Error while filtering: Generic error in an external library
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Generic error in an external library
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[AVIOContext @ 0x6e08a80] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 0x6dc00c0] Statistics: 4970635 bytes read, 0 seeks
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Added `-report` log.

Answer (score 1):

I've just stumbled on the same issue, and here's what I've found:

You're right, you need to tell ffmpeg what color profile is used in the EXR - even if it's pretty standard that they're linear RGB.

So, here's what you need to add before the input:

```
-color_trc linear -color_range pc -color_primaries bt709 -colorspace rgb -i yourFile.exr
```

- `-color_trc`: transfer, `linear`, obviously.
- `-color_range`: pc/full.
- `-color_primaries`: `bt709`, it's the same as RGB actually.
- `-colorspace`: I believe this is the whitepoint, as it has an `rgb` option it's obvious too.